# Is there anything special about command line arguments prefixed with dashes?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, unix

When I do something like:

```
./foo -uxw --bar something
```

Does the shell automatically parse these commands, or does each program have to do the parsing itself?

Comment: the convention here is to usually use single `-` to indicate shortcut of an argument `svn -v` vs `svn --version`.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "parse these commands". If you come with Windows experience, where a program has only one argument (a string), and each program has to do its own splitting into arguments (might be called "parsing" by some). The Unix systems are different: they have unlimited number of string arguments in a form of an array of pointers to a NUL-terminated sequences of bytes. The splitting is done by the running program (the shell, in this case). The interpretation of each argument is left to a program, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the shell doesn't parse it for you. Each program has to parse it on its own. The following code should make it clear what is going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let us compile this program.

```
susam@nifty:~$ gcc args.c -o args
```

Now let us run this and see the output:

```
.susam@nifty:~$ ./args
argc: 1
argv[0] = ./args
susam@nifty:~$ ./args foo bar
argc: 3
argv[0] = ./args
argv[1] = foo
argv[2] = bar
susam@nifty:~$ ./args -a foo --b bar
argc: 5
argv[0] = ./args
argv[1] = -a
argv[2] = foo
argv[3] = --b
argv[4] = bar
```

The only thing the shell does is pass each argument you specify in the command line to your program. While it would pass `foo bar` as two separate arguments to your program, it would pass `"foo bar"` or `'foo bar`' as a single argument to your program. Yes, so the shell does some sort of parsing of the arguments before passing it to your program. It considers quoted strings as a single argument. Here is a demonstration:

```
susam@nifty:~$ ./args -a foo bar
argc: 4
argv[0] = ./args
argv[1] = -a
argv[2] = foo
argv[3] = bar
susam@nifty:~$ ./args -a "foo bar"
argc: 3
argv[0] = ./args
argv[1] = -a
argv[2] = foo bar
susam@nifty:~$ ./args -a 'foo bar'
argc: 3
argv[0] = ./args
argv[1] = -a
argv[2] = foo bar
susam@nifty:~$ ./args -a "foo bar" 'car tar war'
argc: 4
argv[0] = ./args
argv[1] = -a
argv[2] = foo bar
argv[3] = car tar war
```

Answer (score 7):

Each program parses its arguments. You'll probably want to look into [`getopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments) for that so the answer becomes: *each program usually relies on `getopt` to parse arguments*.

Answer (score 1):

Each program has to parse all arguments itself. Prefixing them with dashes is just a Unix convention.

Answer (score 1):

The shell splits the command line on whitespace, so the program receives a list of arguments; but it's up to the program to decide what they mean. Often an argument parsing library like `getopt` is used to help.

Answer (score 0):

Program arguments are not the concern of the shell.

The (simplified) command-line syntax is: *command options operands*.
Options begin with a hyphen (dash) and operands do not, options are not ordered, operands are ordered.

This though is only a convention, not a law.  The most well known standard for this is generally referred to as the POSIX standard, and it defines the command-line [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html).

You may note that options are single characters prefixed with a single hyphen, your example shows two hyphens with multiple-characters `--bar`.  These are known as *long options* and are not strictly part of the standard, although they are commonly used in GNU utility programs (the normal case on Linux).

What happens if an operand begins with a hyphen?  The answer is that most programs will see that as an operand.  There is a special marker though; `--` (two hyphens) which mark the end of the option list, so any that follow are only operands.